# Standardisation with respect to controls

Tags: regression, survival, normalization, standardization, genetics

When performing analyses using polygenic risk scores (PRS),

- Why is it important to standardise/normalise PRSes using mean and sd derived from control samples, before performing analyses, such as logistic regression?
- How would results change if we simply normalised the entire dataset (viz. wrt entire sample's mean and SD)?
- In the [PRSice](https://www.prsice.info/command_detail/) software there is the option to standardize the effect size using mean and sd derived from control samples before calculating the PRS, even. When is this beneficial? How does it compare with standardising the PRS wrt controls afterwards?
- I presume in usual survival analyses, we would only standardisecovariate values wrt the entire sampl, otherwise we would be using future information (i.e. whether they have an event in the followup)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a continuous predictor like a [polygenic risk score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygenic_score) (PRS) there is no need to standardize at all for many regression models. The standardization for new case $i$ given the mean and standard deviation based on control cases $C$ seems to be

$$\text{PRS}^{std_C}_i = \frac{\text{PRS}_i - \overline{\text{PRS}}_{C}}{\sigma_{\text{PRS}_C}} .$$

As this is just a linear transformation of the new sample PRS values, you can transform at will between regression coefficients and intercepts determined with or without standardization. You could standardize instead against the mean and standard deviation of your sample (*sam*)

$$\text{PRS}^{std_{sam}}_i = \frac{\text{PRS}_i - \overline{\text{PRS}}_{sam}}{\sigma_{\text{PRS}_{sam}}}$$

and get the same fundamental results when you back-transform with simple algebra.

Standardization can help avoid some practical numerical problems. For example, the `coxph()` survival function in R internally standardizes predictors to remove problems that can come from exponentiating what would be otherwise arbitrarily large numbers. But it then back-transforms to the original scales before reporting results.

Standardization is important for models that need to place multiple predictors on comparable scales. For example, LASSO and ridge regression penalize the sum of regression coefficient magnitudes or of their squared magnitudes, respectively, so starting with all predictors on comparable scales is important in those types of analyses.

Standardization against controls reports how many (control) standard deviation units a new case is from the control mean value. In that sense it provides a measure of how far from "control" a new case is. That might provide some heuristic value, but such standardization against controls isn't necessary for successful regression.

In terms of survival analysis, if you choose for some reason to standardize you could use any of these standardizations so long as they don't depend on future information about the cases at risk. You could even use control PRS values determined at a later time provided that those control cases aren't included in the survival analysis--all you are doing in that situation is a linear transformation of predictor values.

Comment: +1 Thanks @EdM for the clear explanation! Just to check that I understood correctly -- you are saying that standardisation is a linear transformation so it doesn't affect the model (can scale back) but it helps with interpretation. For survival analyses, we should not use the information of who develops the event during followup to define cases and controls and standardise this way (even though it's just a linear transformation in the end?) 
Re my Q3, this seems different from simply LTing the resulting PRSes, in contrast to Q1,2,4? What are your thought on that?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sufficiently familiar with PRSice to know whether there's anything beyond a series of (invertible) linear transformations involved. You'd have to check the code or ask the program's authors. For survival analysis it's hard to distinguish true cases from true controls, as there's right-censoring of event times. Many true cases won't be observed to have events during a study. That's different from a binary yes/no case/control delineation. You could standardize as you propose, but the heuristic interpretation would be misleading at best.